# Updateing mysql json field in array

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

Having this json:

```
{
    f1: "abc",
    f2: [
        {id: 1, val:"a"},
        {id: 2, val:"b"},
        {id: 3, val:"c"}
    ],
    f3: [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    ]
}
```

Update:
As an example:

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(
'{"f1": "abc", "f2": [{"id": "1", "val":"a"},{"id": "2", "2":"b"},{"id": 3, "val":"2"}], "f3": ["a","b","c"]}',
'all', '1', null, '$.f2[*].id');
```

returns the needed path for f2->id==1
I can then use

```
select json_set(
'{"f1": "abc", "f2": [{"id": "1", "val":"a"},{"id": "2", "2":"b"},{"id": 3, "val":"2"}], "f3": ["a","b","c"]}',
'$.f2[0].val', 'd');
```

to update the data.

but

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(
'{"f1": "abc", "f2": [{"id": 1, "val":"a"},{"id": "2", "2":"b"},{"id": 3, "val":"2"}], "f3": ["a","b","c"]}',
'all', '1', null, '$.f2[*].id');
```

won't find f2->id==1 . Neither does

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH( 
'{"f1": "abc", "f2": [{"id": 1, "val":"a"},{"id": "2", "2":"b"},{"id": 3, "val":"2"}], "f3": ["a","b","c"]}',
'all', 1, null, '$.f2[*].id');
```

=========

update 2:
I will just save the IDs as string... But right now i have onother problem:

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(
'{"mm": [{"id":"1","field":"test","value":33}]}',
'one', '1', null, '$.mm[*].id') as path;
```

is working

```
SELECT *  FROM document_data where document_id=5;
update document_data set data=JSON_SET(data, '$.mm', json_array()) where document_id=5;
update document_data set data=JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(data, '$.mm', '{"id":"1","field":"test","value":33}') where document_id=5;
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(data, 'one', '1', null, '$.mm[*].id') as path from document_data where id='5';
```

is not working. Seems to be the quoting.
Can someone help?

==========

how can i update f2 where id==2 using JSON_SET?

Tried everything but i can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Many thanks
Rene

Comment: If you tried everything then at least post one attempt you did. Post your query that doesn't work so that we may help you to get it working. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your question is not clear and I can't reproduce the new problem you mention, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mYyYHrd4PHDL7nQW1YALKd/0).

Comment: Problem solved. It dis not convert the string to json ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON_SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search), by design, seems to search only strings, see [WL#7909: Server side JSON functions :: JSON_SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7909#JSON_SEARCH()).

One option, very unintuitive is to use something like (be careful with performance problems):

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.20    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @`json` := '{
    '>   "f1": "abc",
    '>   "f2": [
    '>           {"id": 1, "val": "a"},
    '>           {"id": 2, "val": "b"},
    '>           {"id": 3, "val": "c"}
    '>         ],
    '>   "f3": ["a", "b", "c"]
    '> }',
    ->     @`value` := 2,
    ->     @`base_path` := '$.f2';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_SEARCH(
    ->   REPLACE(
    ->     REPLACE(
    ->       REPLACE(
    ->         JSON_EXTRACT(@`json`, CONCAT(@`base_path`, '[*].id')),
    ->       ', ', '","'),
    ->     '[', '["'),
    ->   ']', '"]'),
    -> 'one', @`value`) INTO @`path`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`path`;
+---------+
| @`path` |
+---------+
| "$[1]"  |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   CONCAT(
    ->     REPLACE(
    ->       JSON_UNQUOTE(@`path`),
    ->       '$',
    ->       @`base_path`
    ->     ),
    ->   '.val') INTO @`path`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`path`;
+-------------+
| @`path`     |
+-------------+
| $.f2[1].val |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_SET(@`json`, @`path`, 'd');
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_SET(@`json`, @`path`, 'd')                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"f1": "abc", "f2": [{"id": 1, "val": "a"}, {"id": 2, "val": "d"}, {"id": 3, "val": "c"}], "f3": ["a", "b", "c"]} |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wnehnk489Teee2FeA7M9NZ/0).

Comment: Thanks for this. but that is definitly not what i want ... I will just save the IDs as strings. But i added some more comment. MySQL and JSON does not work that nice it seems ...